# Realm.io accessing objects .lengt on the NSData attribute returns 0

Tags: ios, realm

I've got a problem trying to access my models' NSData attribute. I can see that there is data present in my database (it will increase in size after I've set the imageData attribute). But when trying to access it after setting it, it just returns 0 bytes. It is like it get's nil'ed out somewhere.

I've got the following Entry model that is a child of a Timeline:

```
class Entry: RLMObject {


    dynamic var id               = 0
    dynamic var timelineID  :Int = 0
    dynamic var name        :String = ""
    dynamic var caption     :String = ""
    dynamic var body        :String = ""
    dynamic var imageURL    :String = ""
    dynamic var imageData   :NSData = NSData()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}




//Just a static example. I know my timeline with id 10 has got entries with image data on them
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
let timeline = Timeline.objectsWhere("id == 10").firstObject() as Timeline
let entry = timeline.entries[1] as Entry

//The following println returns 0
println(entry.imageData.length)
```

I feel like I'm fetching my object in a wrong way? Or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Edit: screenshot of the imageData column in the realm browser

[image: Screenshot]

Here is how I set my imageData:

```
cell.cellImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: entry.imageURL), completed: {
    (image, error, imageCache, url) -> Void in
    println(error)
    self.realm.transactionWithBlock {
        entry.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    }
})
```

Comment: Is it possible you're not actually setting the image data, and it's using the default value for the property?

Comment: @segiddins I think the fact that my database increases in size (from about 12kb when data is not set) to about 12mb when the data attr is set means that the data is set?

Comment: That's probably true :) Any chance you could pop the Realm file in the Browser and see what it shows?

Comment: @segiddins look above for a screenshot of the imageData column

Comment: That looks like empty data to me.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So the data is stored somewhere in the file, but not correctly? Is there a correct / wrong way to store the data?

Comment: @segiddins I've added code to show how I set my imageData